# Como faço para mostrar os valores de uma matriz um a um em C? exemplo: linha 1: 1,2 linha 2: 3,4 linha 3: 5,6 " " " " " " " " " "

Tags: c

exemplo:

```
linha 1: 1,2
linha 2: 3,4
linha 3: 5,6
"   "  " " "
"   "  " " "
```

segue o que fiz até o momento:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define max 50

int main()
{


    int m_linhas,n_colunas,matriz[max][max],i=0,j=0;


    scanf("%d%d",&m_linhas,&n_colunas);

    if((m_linhas && n_colunas>0) && (m_linhas && n_colunas <100))
    {

        for(i=0; i<m_linhas; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<n_colunas; j++)
            {
                scanf("%d",&matriz[i][j]);
            }
        }


        for(i=0; i<m_linhas; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<n_colunas; j++)
            {

            printf("linha %d: %d,%d\n",i+=1,matriz[i][j]);

            }
        }
    }

    else
        return 0;


}
```

// Desde já agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente dessa forma:

```
    for(i=0; i<m_linhas; i++){
        //Mostra a linha atual
        printf("\nlinha %d: ", i+1);
        for(j=0; j<n_colunas; j++){
            //Mostra os elementos dessa linha
            printf("%d, ", matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Olá fiz só umas alterações no seu código, seria assim que você queria ?, se quiser eu poder ajudar é só falar

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define max 50

int main()
{


 int m_linhas, n_colunas, matriz[max][max], i = 0, j = 0;


 scanf("%d%d", &m_linhas, &n_colunas);

 if((m_linhas && n_colunas > 0) && (m_linhas && n_colunas < 100))
 {

    for(i = 0; i < m_linhas; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n_colunas; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }


    for(i = 0; i < m_linhas; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n_colunas; j++)
        {
            printf("Linha %d ", i + 1);
            printf("%d\n", matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
 }
 else
 {
    printf("VALOR DIGITADO ULTRAPSSOU O LIMITE PERMITIDO");
 }
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!